# Would this be an easier way to prove the twin prime conjecture?

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, twin-primes

Prove: For every prime, $p\geq7$, there exists some $pn$ such that $p$ is its largest prime factor, $n$ is a positive integer, and $(pn-4, pn-2)$ is a twin prime.

My questions:

1. Would this indeed prove the twin prime conjecture if found to be true? If you say no, why not?
2. Would this perhaps be a simpler method than what is currently being done?
3. How would one go about proving this to be true?

Comment: Brute force, btw, strongly indicates this is true, though that obviously doesn't prove it true.

Comment: For 1., yes, because $pn-4\geq p-4.$ So for $x\in N$ let $p\geq 7$ be prime with $p >x-4,$  and the smaller  member of the twin prime pair is greater than $x.$

Comment: Since this is strictly stronger than the twin prime conjecture, I'd say you need substantial justification for your proposal that it is easier to prove than twin primes.

Comment: "$p$ is its largest prime factor": what is "it"?  Do you mean $n$ (so that $pn$ is in fact divisible by $p^2$) or just $pn$?

Comment: @Erick Edited to better reflect $pn$

Comment: @Erick I think I have the gist, but could you explain what, "strictly stronger" means, and how my proposal is strictly stronger?

Comment: Your proposal is that if you take every twin prime $(q,q+2)$ and bucket them according to the largest prime factor of $q+4$, then every single bucket (of which there are infinitely many) will contain at least one pair of twin primes.  That is a stronger assertion than just that there are infinitely many twin primes.

Comment: @user3363795 I don't use "strictly stronger" in any formal sense, only that it's very easy to deduce twin primes conjecture from your proposal (but not vice versa).  It doesn't appear to offer a simplifying lens to attack the problem, nor does it seem to contribute a substantial step towards it because it is such a short trip from there to twin primes.

Comment: @ErickWong Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Where I thought it might contribute is in specificity of direction. Rather than proving there is or isn't some twin prime after a theoretical "last" twin, or proving smaller and smaller gaps give infinite primes, perhaps proving one bucket must have a twin prime will show other buckets must have more than one (as brute force indicates).

Comment: I said in first post that brute force strongly indicates this is true. Here's a text file showing so: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/Unique%20TwPr%20List.txt . You can subtract 2 from the first twin to get $pn$ then insert it into this website here: to see its factors: http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php .